# What is the Linux equivalent for termiox.h?

Tags: c, linux, rhel

I have an archaic modem interface library, which was originally made for Solaris and Linux, and I am trying to see if it will work for Linux.

While compiling on Linux, I saw :

```
#if ! defined(WIN32)

#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/termiox.h>
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find where termiox.h and when I google for it, it only shows up results for termios.h

I can't simply take away the reference, because there are a number of calls made to it.

Would anyone happen to know where the termiox calls are defined under Linux?

The OS version is RHEL 5.5

The code which references the termiox libraries are just saying it to ignore termiox options:

```
 /home/local/NT/jayanthv/8.7/CallBur/lib/unix.c(556): error: struct "<unnamed>" has no field "termiox"
 if( modem_opt_ignore_termiox == No && ioctl( modem_handle, TCSETX, &mattr_current.termiox ) < 0 )
```

Should I just go ahead and add #if !defined() around the code?

Comment: It seems to come from AIX -- what calls/structs are defined in termiox.h that you need? I.e., what errors do you get when trying to compile without the include? Edit: Our SunOS server also seems to have termiox.

Comment: I have updated the question with the info, do you think it would be wise to just ignore the code calling termiox?

Comment: Hard to say -- I personally would just go ahead and try :) The ioctl call you posted basically sets the flow control settings for modem_handle to the settings in mattr_current.termiox. How is mattr_current.termiox initialized?

Comment: BTW, here's the SunOS termiox man page: http://www-it.desy.de/cgi-bin/man-cgi?termiox+7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No kidding about archaic. At the bottom of the [man page linked by rodion](http://www-it.desy.de/cgi-bin/man-cgi?termiox%207) it says:

> The  termiox(7I) system call is provided  for  compatibility with
>   previous releases and its use is discouraged. Instead, the termio(7I)
>   system call is recommended.

That man page is dated 1990. Since then, [termio has also become obsolete](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html):

> `termio.h` 
>       This header file is obsolete, and has been replaced by `termios.h`, which is part of the POSIX standard. These two header files are very similar. However, the `termios.h` does not include the same header files as `termio.h`. Thus, you should be sure to look directly at the `termios.h` header to make sure it includes everything your application needs.

So termiox was replaced by termio, which was replaced by termios.

Comment: I just removed all references to termiox